# UIButton image resize/scale to fit

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4

I have a really wired problem and i don’t know how to solve it. I’m animating a UIButtons frame and when i animate it, i want the image in the button to scale to the same size as the button. It works without doing anything on my iPhone simulator. But when i run it on the iPad simulator it won’t change the image size. I have added [[gissaImg1 imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill] code on several places but it did not help.

Do anyone know what is wrong and how to fix this problem?

```
//Code to set the image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_small", 
                                              [[itemsForRound objectAtIndex:[[guessItems objectAtIndex:0] intValue]] valueForKey:@"Name"]]];

[self.gissaImg1 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.gissaImg1 setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

//Code to animate button
CGRect animateToSpot = (isIphone) ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320) : CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    [self performSelector:@selector(PlayCorrectSound:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    [[gissaImg1 imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationCurveLinear) animations:^{
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                [[gissaImg1 imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
                [self.gissaImg1 setFrame:animateToSpot];
                [self.view bringSubviewToFront:gissaImg1];
                break;
.......
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try `setBackgroundImage` instead of `setImage`, and do nothing to the image. (resize or setContentMode)
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *thubNailImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumImage"];
[button.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
CGSize imageSize=thubNailImage.size;
[button setImage:thubNailImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -imageSize.width, 0, 0);
```

If you don't want to show the title then remove the last line ( `button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -imageSize.width, 0, 0);`)

I think this is help for someone. :)