# Resize UIImageView with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I've got a view with a `UIButton` in it. I've got some animations that, among others, scale the button down.

The problem is that the button is actually scaling well following the constraints when it only has text, but when I set an image either as its `image` or its `backgroundImage`, the button is not scaling anymore.

I've tried playing with `contentMode`s of both the `UIButton` and its inner `imageView` with no results (I've tried, literally, **all** the possible answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025319/scale-image-in-an-uibutton-to-aspectfit), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957317/how-do-i-scale-a-uibuttons-imageview), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063019/why-does-a-custom-uibutton-image-does-not-resize-in-interface-builder) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246515/uibutton-image-resize-scale-to-fit) stackoverflow questions).

Any hint? Thank you all in advance

**UPDATE**

I've noticed that the issue is with `UIImageView`s, not `UIButton`s (the problem with the button was due to the imageView inside it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got it.

In both cases (UIButton and UIImageView), you have to adjust `Content Compression Resistance Priority` to let the view to scale down. In my case, setting it to `749` was enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think your UIButton does resize, but the ImageView inside does not. The ImageView of the UIButton is always displaying normal image size.

The only possibility I found is to put another UIImageView below the Button with constraints top/bottom/left/right to the Button. This one can be perfectly adjusted.

I use subclassed buttons for that with their own ImageView inside. There you need to be careful to put userInteractionEnabled = false on the ImageView.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but now I've found that adding the image does not work. It must be an issue with UIImageViews

Comment: did you add contentMode.ScaleAspectFit?

Comment: Yes, I tried all. It was an issue with Content Compression Resistance Priority, take a look at my answer